# NSWindow set view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have different sections to my application. I want to have buttons change the view. So, if I click the first button the windows's view will change to another view. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [NSTabView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can make the tab view borderless so that no bezel or tabs are drawn (using `[tabView setTabViewType:NSNoTabsNoBorder]`) and then implement your own button actions to change the views programatically by switching the active tab using `-selectTabViewItem:` or `-selectTabViewItemAtIndex:`. This has the added benefit of being able to configure all of your views in Interface Builder.

Comment: You can also set the tab view type in IB.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: Sample project that uses this code:

[SwitchView.zip](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/SwitchView.zip)

[image]

You can use the following categories on `NSWindow` to implement switching from one view to another.

MDAppKitAdditions.h:

```
@interface NSWindow (MDAdditions)
- (CGFloat)toolbarHeight;
- (void)resizeToSize:(NSSize)newSize;
- (void)switchView:(NSView *)aView title:(NSString *)aString;
- (void)switchView:(NSView *)aView;
@end
```

MDAppKitAdditions.m:

```
static NSView *blankView() {
    static NSView *view = nil;
    if (view == nil) view = [[NSView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

@implementation NSWindow (MDAdditions)

- (CGFloat)toolbarHeight {
    NSToolbar *toolbar = self.toolbar;
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = 0.0;
    if (toolbar && toolbar.isVisible) {
        NSRect windowFrame = [[self class] contentRectForFrameRect:self.frame
                                                     styleMask:self.styleMask];
        toolbarHeight = NSHeight(windowFrame) - NSHeight([self.contentView frame]);
    }
    return toolbarHeight;
}

- (void)resizeToSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    CGFloat newHeight = newSize.height + [self toolbarHeight];
    CGFloat newWidth = newSize.width;
    NSRect aFrame = [[self class] contentRectForFrameRect:self.frame
                                                styleMask:self.styleMask];
    aFrame.origin.y += aFrame.size.height;
    aFrame.origin.y -= newHeight;
    aFrame.size.height = newHeight;
    aFrame.size.width = newWidth;
    aFrame = [[self class] frameRectForContentRect:aFrame
                                         styleMask:self.styleMask];
    [self setFrame:aFrame display:YES animate:YES];
}

- (void)switchView:(NSView *)aView title:(NSString *)aTitle {
    if (self.contentView != aView) {
        [self setContentView:blankView()];
        if (aTitle) [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(aTitle, @"")];
        [self resizeToSize:aView.frame.size];
        [self setContentView:aView];
    }
}

- (void)switchView:(NSView *)aView {
    return [self switchView:aView title:nil];
}

@end
```

To use it, I assume you would have a controller class like the following, with IBOutlets for views and your main window:

```
@interface MDAppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow  *mainWindow;
    IBOutlet NSView    *firstView;
    IBOutlet NSView    *secondView;
}

- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then in your implementation, something like this:

```
#import "MDAppKitAdditions.h"

@implementation MDAppController

- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tag = [sender tag];
    NSView *targetView = nil;

    if (tag == 0) {
       targetView = firstView;
    else if (tag == 1) {
       targetView = secondView;
    }
    [mainWindow switchView:targetView title:@"New window title"];
}

@end
```

You could set it up so that the buttons you want to use to switch views each call the same `changeView:` method instead of defining separate methods for each one. In the nib file in Interface Builder, you can set the tag property of the buttons to differentiate between them. At runtime, when you click the button and it calls the `changeView:` method, the button is passed in as the generic `sender` parameter, so you then examine that to determine which view you should switch to.

Comment: @PeterHosey: OK, for a simple interface, this is probably overkill. However, being the experienced guy you are, I hope you can imagine how the tab view approach could become detrimental as app complexity increases. Case in point, the inherited project I've been working on for the last 4 months. The novice original developer (sorry Bernardo) implemented entire app UI in a single (2 MB!) nib file. The 16 tab view items, 10 table views, 100s of text fields, all loaded whether they will actually be used or not, lead to a long launch time and decreased performance. Will update my answer...